# В чём разница между var obj{} и var obj[]?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Ведь и то, и то массив, но разница есть.

Например:

```
var users = [ {"name":"Kurusa", "pass":"Kurusa123"}, {"name":"Zhecky", "pass":"Zhecky123"}, {"name":"Marko", "pass":"Marko123"}, {"name":"Polo", "pass":"Polo123"} ];
```

И вот так:

```
var user = { name: "Вася" };
```

Comment: и то, и другое - некорректный код

Comment: Не совсем. Например: var users = [
  {"name":"Kurusa", "pass":"Kurusa123"},
  {"name":"Zhecky", "pass":"Zhecky123"},
  {"name":"Marko", "pass":"Marko123"},
  {"name":"Polo", "pass":"Polo123"}
]; И вот так :                                                                       var user = {
  name: "Вася"
};

Comment: читайте:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp , https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Comment: Спасибо) Просто я никак не могла задать гуглу корректный вопрос и найти ответ

Comment: Обратите внимание что у вас в комментарии написано не то же самое что и в заголовке

Comment: Ну в том то и дело, что я не знала как это обозначить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспринимайте массив `var users = [{}, {}, {}];` как коробку с пончиками. 
А, собственно, `{}` как пончик.

У "пончика" есть свойства, которые представляются парами ключ: значение. Например `{"тип":"шоколадный", "вес":102.5}`.

А коробка на то и есть коробка, она только может вмещать другие вещи (коробки, пончики и другое), и давать возможность доступа к ним по порядку, узнать сколько их всего и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, объект - это не массив.

Словарём его с натяжкой ещё можно назвать, но точно не массивом.
Массив содержит некоторое число элементов один за другим и имеет длину.
Объект содержит именованные свойства с некими значениями.